# creating a php and curl call back function

Tags: php, web-services, curl

I am trying to get a post response from a server as at when it is sent, and update my database. The code that I have so far only gets a response when I run in through the browser but it does not get any further responses from the server. This is my code so far:

```
if($ch !== false){
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    //Attach our encoded JSON string to the POST fields.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    //Set the content type to application/json
    // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose',
        'Content-length:' . strlen($jsonDataEncoded))
    );
}

//Execute the request
$result = curl_exec($ch);

if ($result === false){
    curl_close($ch);
    echo "Error".curl_errno($ch). "\n";
}
else {
    curl_close($ch);
    $decoded = json_decode($result, true);

    $data['unique_id'] = $decoded["clientCorrelator"];
    $data['subscriber_number'] = $decoded["endUserId"];
    $data['payment_status'] = $decoded["transactionOperationStatus"];
    $data['payment_gross'] = $decoded["paymentAmount"]["totalAmountCharged"];
    $data['txn_id'] = $decoded["ecocashReference"];

    $this->payments->insertTransaction($data);
    die;
}
```

Comment: Can you please post a minimum example that demonstrates the behavior?

Comment: this is all that i have its still a concept. basically my question is how can i get capture anything that is  sent by the server in json format, just like what is done by the paypal IPN

Comment: This site is not meant for helping with concepts. Come back to us when you have a concrete problem that needs solving.